# Jacobi Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently doing some research into Jacobi matrices and I'm currently trying to find the explicit characteristic polynomial for small n for the matrices where there is $0$'s in the diagonal and $1$'s in the diagonals above and below the $0$'s.

For example where $n=4$

$\mathbf{X}=\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0}&{1}&{0}&{0}\\
{1}&{0}&{1}&{0}\\
{0}&{1}& {0} &{1}\\
{0}&{0}&{1}&{0}
\end{array}\right]$

I have worked out the characteristic polynomial for n=2,3,4,5 and have seen some more of pattern by working out the upper triangular matrix, however can't seem to figure out an explicit polynomial.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/m171.dir/sec_9-4.pdf

The complete calculation for your problem has been done there before.

So from that paper: Take a look at $A$. Choose $\alpha_i = 0$ and $\beta_i = 1$.
Then they define the characteristic polynomial for $n=1$. Something like $\chi_1(\lambda)=\alpha_1 - \lambda$ (in the paper they call it $f$).
In your case this would be: $\chi_1(\lambda)= -\lambda$. And as a convention define: $\chi_0(\lambda)= 1$.

Then for larger matrices, define recursively:

$$\chi_n(\lambda) = -\lambda \cdot \chi_{n-1}(\lambda) - \chi_{n-2}(\lambda)$$

Comment: Hi, I've read through the link a few times and can't seem to figure out how to apply it in order for me to get an explicit characteristic polynomial.